# Trying to get an ImageView on a ScrollView to autosize in a PageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, autolayout

Ya, that's a mouthful. I've created a PageControl with an [ImageScrollView](https://github.com/huynguyencong/ImageScrollView) on the data controller. This allows the user to page through images and zoom in on any of them, without negatively impacting the paging. The only problem is that the AutoLayout no longer works. I can't seem to figure out how to apply AutoLayout to this scenario? The problem is that the image being displayed is not full screen. It is always whatever size the controller was set to in Xcode. e.g. if Xcode set to iPhone 7 Plus for design, and you run it on an iPhone 7, the image is too big. In reverse, it's too small. I've tried every possible combination of AutoLayout on the scrollview, with no success whatsoever.

I'm very new to ScrollViews, so am having a bit of a struggle figuring out how to get the image inside the scrollview to start out at full screen and to return to full screen when you double tap while zoomed.

Any suggestions appreciated.

*Edit: It appears the problem is related to the paging, as the image starts out at full screen, then once paged, the image is smaller.